# Capture and Record Desktop Screen with/as Webcam Video

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, window, screen-recorder, virtual-webcam

Webcam lets others view either still pictures or motion video of a user or other object in front of it. I want to configure Webcam in a way that it start capturing desktop screen instead of what is in front of it.

I want to manipulate desktop screen captured through Webcam using FFMPEG library. Such as:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -f mp4 cam_stream.mp4
```

I want to use this same application to capture my Desktop Screen that will be possible just in that case when Webcam will be able to capture my Desktop Screen instead. So above command will start recording what Webcam will be capturing that I want it to capture my desktop screen.

**Note:** I know other ways to capture, record or stream desktop screen but I want to achieve it through Webcam.

**What I tried so far:**
I tried some Fake/Virtual Webcam software (manycam, sparkocam etc.) but I don't think they fulfil what I exactly want.

Please guide me if there is any way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: you want to be able to flip between them easily? or overlay one on the other?

Comment: Hi Roger,  
Actually I have an application which records what is being captured by Webcam. So, I want to use that application for screen capturing. And this will be possible if I somehow manage to configure webcam to capture my desktop screen instead of what it captures normally. If there is any way I could give Desktop Screen Capture stream to Webcam as input.

Comment: I can capture desktop screen and also webcam stream and I want webcam to take desktop capture stream as input.

Comment: you want the physical device "webcam" to capture your desktop?

Comment: Yes I want this. I am looking for some way that Webcam start taking Desktop Captured Stream as Input. Any fake behavior

Comment: so you probably are looking for some wrapper that takes input from "either one" and displays it.  I've heard of amerectv before it might help.  What is your end goal, flip between desktop and webcam during a recording?

Comment: Yes, When I run particular command (ffmpeg) it start capturing my desktop screen to record instead of what WebCam capture normally.

Comment: Actually, When I will be opening My Webcam with some command it will be taking Desktop as input while in other cases it will work normally.

Comment: do you want it to take desktop input initially then "switch" to the real webcam?

Comment: yes. When I access it with some FFMPEG command with some specified parameters then It should take input from desktop while in other normal cases it should work with its default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

OK ffmpeg has a "gdigrab" option that takes from the desktop, and then "dshow" option to separately capture webcam.  If you want "all of that to come from one device" then you might be able to get it by install screen-capture-recorder then setting up some "intermediary splitting" dshow filter (which can take input from different sources) like possibly AmerecTV or a splitter of some type https://stackoverflow.com/q/2878187/32453 sorry I dont' know much more, GL!

Comment: Thanks a lot @rogerdpack for all your efforts in helping me. I will give it a try and will come back to you with status.